# Extracting all components of a composite type?

Tags: json, postgresql

If I run:

```
with fields as (
    select jsonb_each_text(jsonb_array_elements('[
        {"a":1},
        {"b":2},
        {"c":3}]')) x
)
select (x).key, (x).value from fields;
```

I get:

```
 key | value 
-----+-------
 a   | 1
 b   | 2
 c   | 3
(3 rows)
```

This works fine, but I'm looking for a way to extract these fields (`key` and `value`) without having to specify them by hand. In other words, can I expand the composite-typed values from the inner query directly, without having to individually name the pieces (`key` and `value`) I want to extract? This would be something like an inverse of the `ROW` function (which creates a composite type from individual vaues)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
with fields as (
    select json_each_text(json_array_elements('[
        {"a":1},
        {"b":2},
        {"c":3}]')) x
)
select (x).* from fields;
```